# Where is directory of the pcl source codes?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi my friends,

I am a newbie and working on kinect with pcl on ROS.
I can run the tutorials on the ros website, but the weird thing is that i cannot find the  implementation of all the class I have imported.

eg. `#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>`

I can find the headfile is in  `/opt/ros/groovy/include/pcl-1.6/pcl/filters/extract_indices.h`
but i cannot find its corresponding .cpp file.
I thought it must be inside `/opt/ros/groovy/stack/`, but it is not there.

Could anyone to clear my doubts?

Thanks a lot in advance!

JK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97151/where-is-directory-of-the-pcl-source-codes?/) by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2013-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will be there in `/opt/ros/groovy/share/` if its not there in `/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/`.

Or wherever it is, just locate it using command `locate extract_indices.cpp` in ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) with karma: 311 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1